# Ethereum Account setup, connect with the blockchain and keep tracks of the updates

Tags: ethereumj, java

I have a `Bitcoin` wallet developed in `Java/Spring MVC` and supports account setup, connect with the blockchain and keep tracks of the updates such as the balance, transactions etc. The sample code provided,

```
public class WalletModel {

    // keep tracks of the updates in the wallet
    private void update(Wallet wallet) {

          this.balance = wallet.getBalance();

    this.address = wallet.currentReceiveAddress();

    transactions.addAll(wallet.getRecentTransactions(100, false));

    // find to most recent transaction
    this.transaction = Objects.isNull(transactions) ||
            transactions.isEmpty() ? "No transaction" : String.valueOf(transactions.get(0));
  }

public boolean setWallet(Wallet wallet) {

    try {

        wallet.addChangeEventListener(new WalletChangeEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWalletChanged(Wallet wallet) {
                update(wallet);
            }
        });
        update(wallet);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
     }
 }
```

The `WalletManager` code e.g,

```
public class WalletManager {

      public static WalletAppKit bitcoin;
      public static NetworkParameters networkParameters = 
 TestNet3Params.get();

public static WalletManager setupWallet(final String walletName) {

        logger.info("Setup Wallet");

        WalletManager walletManager = new WalletManager();
        walletManager.setupWalletKit(walletName);

        try {
            if (walletManager.bitcoin.isChainFileLocked()) {
                return walletManager;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return walletManager;
        }

        walletManager.bitcoin.startAsync();
        return walletManager;
    }

private void setupWalletKit(final String walletId) {

        File directory = getWalletDirectory(walletId);

        // if the seed is not null, that means we are restoring from the backup
        bitcoin = new WalletAppKit(networkParameters, directory, WALLET_FILE_NAME) {

            @Override
            protected void onSetupCompleted() {

                // Don't make the user wait for confirmations
                // they're sending their own money anyway!!
                bitcoin.wallet().allowSpendingUnconfirmedTransactions();
                Wallet wallet = bitcoin.wallet();

                model.setWallet(wallet);
                setupCompletedListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onSetupCompleted(wallet));
            }
        };

        // Now configure and start the appkit. This will take a second or two - we could show a temporary splash screen
        // or progress widget to keep the user engaged whilst we initialise, but we don't.
        if (networkParameters == RegTestParams.get()) {
            bitcoin.connectToLocalHost();   // You should run a regtest mode bitcoind locally.
        } else if (networkParameters == TestNet3Params.get()) {
            bitcoin.useTor();
        }

        bitcoin.setDownloadListener(model.getSyncProgressUpdater())
                .setBlockingStartup(false)
                .setUserAgent(APP_NAME, "1.0");
    }
}
```

How to write similar operations in the Ethereum with Java?

UPDATE

I use `maven` for the development and use `EthereumJ` dependency e.g;

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ethereum</groupId>
            <artifactId>ethereumj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This seems fine as there is no error in the `POM` file. When I tried to import in the source file, I get the `RED` errors,

[image]

I have tried with other version of the dependencies as well.  What os the issue here?

Comment: One place you can check is https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj

Comment: Does it provide all the supports as of `BitcoinJ`?

Comment: If I were you, I would use [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j). I use it an I really like it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it be easier to use an api to monitor account details. For instance [Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io/) has a way to get the details about an account that you are looking for. You can try it out [here](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference#reference-getting-started)!

Answer (score 0):

In order to acquire dependency by maven you should add this to your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ethereum</id>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/ethereum/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

because artifacts were not published on the central http://maven.org/